# During execution of Swift code getting error "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: swift

I am just creating object of this class. Previously I didn't get this error from around 1 week. Suddenly I am getting this error:

[image: error page]

For workaround I initialize classes like `var contactEducationDtls:ContactEducationDtlsVO?;`

Comment: I would check the constructor of that class. It might be trying to access something that's unavailable.

Comment: The stack also looks odd as if a ContactVO creates a ContactAgentMappingVO which creates another ContactVO and repeat.  If you scroll down that stack, how many frames deep does it go?

Comment: I think @PhillipMills is right.  That looks like you went into an infinite loop and, well, got a stack overflow. ;-)

Comment: yes I removed that line to stop recursion.
but what is wrong with "var contactEducationDtls=ContactEducationDtlsVO()" declaration